# How do I open a webpage and run a javascript command on it programatically?

Tags: javascript, loading, html

I would like to create an executable file on my desktop that, when run, opens a web page on an internet browser and executes a javascript command on it. I don't care what language is used to do this. E.g., I would be very happy if someone could point me to a C command that could run javascript on a webpage.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but I'm struggling because I don't have much experience in managing external applications.

I am not trying to create a webpage that links to another and runs javascript on that (cross-site scripting).

Comment: You want an external program to open the page and that this executes the JS on this site, not the browser? I know that you can execute JS as a bookmark in Firefox.

Comment: What operating system? What are the requirements and preferences? (ex. what browser?, is it necessary for this to use current browser profile or a specific profile?) Is it OK to create a local proxy server and make the browser use that? (that would be a simple solution)

Comment: Just make the page execute the JavaScript on load?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do: make an external execute javascript on load.

Comment: @Pierre  I'm rather lost on any solutions. I can open up a browser and load a webpage easily in several languages, but the running javascript on said page I have no solutions for.

Comment: The question is still unclear. You can actually send messages to windows (ex. your browser) to open a bookmark. Rather than using `C` you can save your time and use tools like `AutoIt` or `AutoHotKey` to automate opening a bookmark in a browser. And also don't forget user scripts. they are javascripts that executed on certain url patterns. you can easily write one for `Firefox` or `Chrome`. Also `Safari` extensions are very easy to develop.

Comment: @hellectronic Is it possible to executive Javascript bookmarks programatically?

Comment: I mean, inside the page, make it so the JavaScript executes when the page loads. That way, as soon as you load it, which you already know how to do, it will execute.

Comment: @fardjad I'm sorry that my post is unclear. I do not want to simulate a mouse movement to click on a bookmark like AutoHotKey would do. I'm looking for something like a command-line solution - an executable that will do this directly.

Comment: C#'s WebBrowser class has an InvokeScript method, but the class doesn't start a WebBrowser, it *is* a WebBrowser.

Comment: @farjad I'm looking into userscripts, though. This seems very useful.

Comment: @Xeon06 Thank you, I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

`firefox -new-window 'javascript:alert("test")'` this will start a new Firefox window and will run the script. Maybe you can use the JS `window` or `document` object to load a url first.